# How to get mobile number from Smartface App Studio?

Tags: smartface.io

As I need to include OTP process for my App linking up with mobile number, I am planning to auto populate the user mobile number by default in my app screen. 
Can any help in getting mobile number using Smartface App Studio

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get user's phone number. It is something related with the operator.